# Using #define for text replacement in the code

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Apparently, I can set

```
#define LIMIT 50
```

to say that LIMIT, wherever it occurs in the code, is replaced by 50.

Is it possible to use

```
#define ui "unsigned int"
```

to define my variables in such a way?

```
ui foo = 42
ui bar = 99
```

Comment: Example of problems with using such a define: if you define a variable with 'ui' in the name it will be replaced as well: let's say you define a function doing stuff on a user interface (often shortened "UI") and you define the function as follows:
void uiFoo();
Preprocessor will replace ui and the line will end up beind void "unsigned int"Foo(); which will cause syntax error. Long story short : don't do stuff like that, use typedef.

Comment: @PierreBaret: No, that's nonsense. Macro replacement works on tokens, not on individual characters within a token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the preprocessor for replacement is not recommended and can lead to unexpected problems.

For your use-case there is the `typedef` or `using` statement:

Use:

```
using ui = unsigned int;
```

Or:

```
typedef unsigned int ui;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: Be careful when using using to abbreviate names of types. The time gained for your initial code coding is going to be lost by either you or other people trying to understand your code (in the future). Aliases should mostly be used to show intent (add meaning), or increase readabilty. For example your unsigned int represents a type you want to use for counters then : using count_t = unsigned int; makes sense. Because your code becomes more readable e.g. void count_to(count_t count);

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with

```
#define ui "unsigned int"
```

The first is that the macro replacement is a *string* and not a type.

The second is that such macros (and even type-aliases) tend to make the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

MACRO just does text replacement, so with:

```
#define ui "unsigned int"
ui foo = 42;
ui bar = 99;
```

you got, after substitution

```
"unsigned int" foo = 42;
"unsigned int" bar = 99;
```

which is invalid.

Syntax would be:

```
#define ui unsigned int
```

But better to use typedef here (so scope and type are respected):

old school:

```
typedef unsigned int ui;
```

modern way:

```
using ui = unsigned int;
```